# How can two RPMs be mutually exclusive providers of the same functionality?

Tags: rpm

I have a `breakfast` package that `Requires` `toast`, `bacon`, and `eggs`. Importantly, `breakfast` needs exactly one `eggs` implementation to be a balanced meal.

The `scrambled-eggs` package `Provides` `eggs`. So does the `fried-eggs` package. In no circumstance should `scrambled-eggs` be installed alongside `fried-eggs`, even in the absence of `breakfast`.

If there were only two ways to prepare eggs, the solution would be to add `Conflicts: fried-eggs` to the `scrambled-eggs` package and vice versa. However, there are many ways to prepare eggs, some of which aren't even known yet, and a new way of preparing eggs might not be familiar with all of the other ways to prepare eggs.

Interestingly, it seems that for RPM version 4.11.3, you can make each package have both `Provides: eggs` and `Conflicts: eggs`, but this behavior does not seem to be documented. In fact, the [documentation](http://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html) seems to suggest that it should not work:

> Conflicts are basically inverse Requires. If there is a matching package the package cannot be installed. It does not matter whether the Conflict: tag is on the already installed or to be installed package.

Can I rely on the above Provides/Conflicts behavior for future versions of RPM? Or, how else can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure these packages cannot be installed side by side, even if they provide similar functionality? For instance, `postfix` and `sendmail` both provide `MTA` but can be installed together (even if it seemingly doesn't make much sense).

Comment: `breakfast` is out of my control and consumes all files in `/usr/local/lib/ingredients`. I control `eggs`. If multiple `eggs` are installed into `/usr/local/lib/ingredients`, `breakfast` won't work properly. So no, they cannot be installed side by side, unless I inject another step outside of the package (ex: symlink), and that would be unfortunate. I could also use a dummy file that all egg providers agree to provide so that they would conflict on file resolution, but that feels dirty as well.

Comment: With the example of `postfix` and `sendmail`, they hook into the alternatives framework so you can install both but you use alternatives to select which is the active one.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

It's not about "functionality".

"Provides -  usually lists which files are provided (full path) and "tags" (toast, bacon, egg) are included. "Tags" (let's interpret it this way) SHOULD be unique to something very specific, not the functionality like MTA's or so.

You get conflicts, when multiple versions of packages of same name are not allowed or "Provides" match.

Basically, you SHOULD NOT interpret "provides" as "functionality". That's the idea.